# Displaying in ListItem in React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem displaying several texts with condition in my `ListItemText` secondary. It should display that several specific country(s) if that condition is met. The problem now is that its not displaying

Here's my code

```
<ListItemText
  primary="Place(s) you been to"
  secondary={
    (`${formData?.Italy ? "You can go Italy " : ""}`,
    `${formData?.France ? "Hello France " : ""}`,
    `${formData?.Portugal ? "Welcome to Portugal " : ""}`,
    `${formData?.Spain ? "Hi Spain" : ""}`)
  }
/>;
```

If i just did this it works

```
secondary={formData?.Italy ? "You can go to Italy " : ""}
```

Comment: what is the problem, and what is an example of your expected?

Comment: @hgb123. it should display that specific country if that condition is met. The problem now is that its not displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If display one specific country only, you should chain using ternary operator instead

```
secondary={ `${
  formData?.Italy
    ? "Italy "
    : formData?.France
    ? "France "
    : formData?.Portugal
    ? "Portugal"
    : formData?.Spain
    ? "Spain"
    : ""
}` }
```

For multiple ones

```
secondary={ `${["Italy", "France", "Portugal", "Spain"]
  .filter((country) => formData?.[country])
  .join(", ")}`
}
```

Updated after question changed

```
secondary={
    `${formData?.Italy ? "You can go Italy " : ""}`+
    `${formData?.France ? "Hello France " : ""}`+
    `${formData?.Portugal ? "Welcome to Portugal " : ""}`+
    `${formData?.Spain ? "Hi Spain" : ""}`
  }
```

If you want comma between each

```
secondary={ [
  `${formData?.Italy ? "You can go Italy" : ""}`,
  `${formData?.France ? "Hello France" : ""}`,
  `${formData?.Portugal ? "Welcome to Portugal" : ""}`,
  `${formData?.Spain ? "Hi Spain" : ""}`,
].filter(Boolean).join(", ") }
```

Comment: It can display several countries thats why i put a comma on each

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
Italy is a variable, France is a variable, Portugal is a variable and Spain is also a variable. If the value of Italy,  or France or Portugal or Spain is true then I will display "Italy" etc......

Comment: @Joseph `formData?.['Italy']`  and `formData?.Italy` are the same, FYI

Comment: Ok. but for example if i want to display the value differently like if Italy is true, then i will display "You can go to Italy". Something like that

Comment: @Joseph then use `+` instead of `,`

Comment: @Joseph if you want comma between each, wrap all into an array, filter the non-empty ones, and join the filtered by comma